# [android]Java script to Java native Bindings & vice versa

Tags: javascript, android

I am a working on developing web applications where we are trying to access Native functionality in the phone using Java script APIs.

Android Web view supports "AddJavascript" interface for Java script to Java (native) bindings as in below link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

BUT if I need to pass data back to Java script there is no API or mechanism to do so in Android.
Could any please let me know if there is a way out, tried hard using JSON as below by we cannot pass all kinds of values using JSON

HTML with JS

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function OnClick(){    
    var nativeStr = window.native.getValue();
    window.native.callBack();
    }

function JScallback(data) {
}
</script>


WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.MyWebView);

NativeClass myNative = new NativeClass (wv);

wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.addJavascriptInterface(myNative, "native");
wv.loadUrl("file:///html/test.html");

public class NativeClass{

private WebView mWebView;

public NativeClass  (WebView appView) {
    this.mWebView = appView;
}

public String getValue() {
    return "Native Value";
}  


public void callBack() {
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
try {
    result.put("Name", "Android Dev"); 
    arr.put(result);
} catch (Exception ex) {

}       

mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:JScallback(" + arr.toString() + ")");

}
```

Thanks in advance,
Android Dev.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote when you [cross-posted this](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ad9a0d5307ff514c#) to the `android-developers` Google Group:

> Call `loadUrl("javascript:...")`, where the `...` is your JavaScript 
>   source code. That JavaScript source will be executed in the context of 
>   whatever Web page is presently loaded. This is the same technique that 
>   "bookmarklets" use.